# Randomly display activity posts on home page with buddypress

Tags: plugins, posts, buddypress, code

I have a buddypress with a theme (youzify), I want to display activity posts randomly on home page, not in chronological order. Anyone knows any code or method for that?

I used this code but it doesn't work buddypress

```
function posts_random_order( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {

        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );

    }

}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'posts_random_order' );
```

Answer (score 0):

And why not using simple wordpress code, changing args ?

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'orderby'        => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page' => '1',
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            $my_query->the_post();

            /* do your post output here */

        } // end while
    } // end if
```

Comment: This code does not work with buddypress

Comment: Hi, what is the error shown ?